# IntelliJ debugger: Connects but doesn't notice when code runs into breakpoints

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic, remote-debugging

I try to debug an application server (WebLogic) with IntelliJ IDEA 11.1 Ultimate. The debugger configuration worked previously, I didn't change anything.

What happens is: IntelliJ tells me

> Connected to the target VM, address: '[snip]:9009', transport: 'socket'

I can add and remove breakspoints, and they are marked with a check mark, so setting them seems to work. By interacting with the web interface of my application, I try to hit the breakpoints I set. The breakpoint actually seem to stop the code from executing, but the IntelliJ debugger doesn't react. The web interface of my application doesn't respond until I disconnect the debugger, but IntelliJ just doesn't seem to notice that this happens at all. I cannot interact with the debugger. How can I figure out what goes wrong? Is there some debugging output of the IntelliJ debugger itself? Are there known solutions to this issue?

Comment: I'm facing weird debbuger issues when there is a mismatch between source code and deployed code. Are you sure that actual version is deployed ?

Comment: Yes, I deploy it directly in IntelliJ with an Ant task, it's guaranteed to match the version installed on the application server.

Comment: Once you think the app has reached the breakpoint, hit the 'pause' button in the debugger and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, solved it: I had a method breakpoint active. Apparently that slowed the whole debugging process down so much that I couldn't interact with the debugger. Once I removed the breakpoint, debugging worked again.

Answer (score 3):

I had actually the same problem using Remote debugger. 
I fixed it by clicking on "pause" button
[Picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q52cM.png)

Comment: Had the same issue. The debugger would not stop in any break point, nor jump to any particular place in the code, while the application seems to be blocked. 

Even restarting IntelliJ would not help.

Simply triggering a pause and then resuming again did the trick. Thanks mate (y)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but with a slight variation. I can mark and remove the breakpoints, the debugger was connected, shows all the threads of the JVM but the execution does not stop for any breakpoint.

Also it shows the old breakpoints as valid even after the code has been changed. It so happened, that even after un-deploying the war file, the break points are still shown as valid breakpoints. That was weird!!

Just as a note, I was using CE as below:
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 
Build #IC-145.1617, built on June 3, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_65-b17 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

I tried different things:

1. Invalidate Cache.
2. Invalidate Cache and Restart
3. Re-package the war and re-deployed it

None of the above worked.

After this, I tried deleting the .idea folder and recreated the project. This time it is created the .idea folder again with the configuration afresh.

The breakpoints now worked.

I posted so that it would help others who would have the same case as mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where my app didn't stop at breakpoints and all I had to was restart IntelliJ Idea. And voila, now it does stop at breakpoints.

My application was running and on console, it printed:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then, when I ran my IntelliJ debugger, it printed:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '192.168.2.9:5005', transport: 'socket'
```

Which is still the same after restart, but somehow restart makes it right for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after I yanked out one of my debug phones (being Android I need many phones to debug) and quickly whipped in another.

It's happened before, and I usually either,

a) use Linux instead

b) save for a bigger brand/better driver phone

c) `adb kill-server` / `adb start-server`

These have some measure of success and are preferable for me to recreating my project. What I understand from Android support is I should be using a Nexus with Linux for any kind of support, which is pretty much obviating any cross compilation / debugging I would like to benefit from.

Even the phone I yanked is now (24 hours later) refusing to honour breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you and my Java host cmd is started from raw java command `java -cp ...`

But the solution is more weird for me... **I downloaded the maven sources and it works...**

Before downloading sources, I tried use pause in debugger(because it never stop so I want to check where it goes) and it is continuously stuck in one line of code in my dependency jar. After source is downloaded, it is not stuck and the breakpoints works.....

Hope this help for anyone.