# IntelliJ remote debugger connects, but breakpoints are not working

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatra

I am trying out the Scala web framework Scalatra. According to the docs [here](http://scalatra.org/getting-started/ide-support.html), the steps to enable IntelliJ debugging are:

1. Add the usual JDK options for remote debugging: `"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"`
2. Create a "Remote" run configuration in Intellij
3. Start up `sbt`, run `jetty:start`, and then start the remote debugger

When I do this, SBT prints out:

`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`

And IntelliJ prints:

`Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'`

However, breakpoints do not seem to be working. When I hit the following endpoint, with a breakpoint at the `*`:

```
class AppServlet extends AppStack {
  get("/break-test") {
*   val response = "DONE"
    response
  }
}
```

The code does not stop at that line, but continues so I get the response `DONE` back.

I am using Java 1.8.0_111, Scala 2.12, and SBT 0.13.15.

Comment: I solved this by downloading the maven sources.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550026/intellij-debugger-connects-but-doesnt-notice-when-code-runs-into-breakpoints/71231272#71231272

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I use for remote debugging:

> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,addres‌​s=5005.

The value you use above in your answer, `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`, is used in the `For JDK 1.4.x` field.

Answer (score 5):

Ah finally, After big struggle ! I found it for me !

I needed to disable forking in build.sbt

```
 fork in Test := false,
```

It makes total sense, as it's only the first JVM who would get to be attach to the IDE.

I hope it help someone !

Answer (score 0):

When you start SBT with -jvm-debug you are attaching the debugger to that SBT process, jetty:start will fork and run jetty in a new process. To be able to debug your app, you must set the var debugPort in build.sbt (`.settings(debugPort in Jetty := 5005`)) or insider SBT repl (`set debugPort in Jetty := 5005`) and then start jetty by using `jetty:debug` (I'm assuming you are using `xsbt-web-plugin`).

Comment: Ah OK, I saw somewhere else that jetty runs on the same JVM as SBT but will give this a go

Comment: I had to use xsbt-web-plugin 3.0 for this to work, this is the code in plugin.sbt: `addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "3.0.0")`

Comment: This made a lot of sense, but did not work. I have:

`addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "3.0.1")`

And then

`> set debugPort in Jetty := 5005`
`> jetty:debug`

Which prints out:

`> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`

And I run Debug from IntelliJ to get:

`Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'`

But still no luck with the breakpoints :-(

Comment: OK so my IntelliJ is out of date by ~1 year so let me update this!

Comment: also, this is what I use in intellij for remote debugging: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`. What you show above is used in the `For JDK 1.4.x `

Comment: That worked! Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it? I didn't need to use `xsbt-web-plugin` or `set debugPort in Jetty := 5005`

Comment: but, did you need to use jetty:debug?

Answer (score 0):

In the [Scalatra docs](https://scalatra.org/getting-started/ide-support.html), step 1 says to update the javaOptions in the `build.scala` file. Instead, updating the `build.sbt` file fixed the issue for me. After updating the correct file, the rest of the steps in the docs worked perfectly.

#### build.sbt

```
val ScalatraVersion = "2.7.1"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"

lazy val hello = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "My Scalatra Web App",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
      "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalatest" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % "runtime",
      "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.4.35.v20201120" % "container",
      "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
    ),
    javaOptions ++= Seq(
      "-Xdebug",
      "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
    ),
  )

enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)
enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
```